# Nginx редирект всех урлов с ru на основной домен

Tags: nginx

Необходимо сделать редирект
с url вида

```
<domain>/ru/tkani-na-avto
```

на url

```
<domain>/tkani-na-avto
```

Пробовал следующий вариант, но не сработало

```
if ($query_string ~ "^(.*)/ru/$") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri permanent;
}
```

Comment: В вашем варианте вы почему-то прописали `/ru/` в конце ссылки, хотя в вашем примере url `/ru/` стоит в начале

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если всё же верить описанию, то так:

```
location ^~ /ru/ {
    #rewrite /ru(.+) $1 permanent;
    rewrite /ru(.+) $1 redirect;
}
```

В процессе поиска правильного конфига не стоит использовать постоянный редирект. Потому что браузер его запомнит и вам надо будет чистить кеш браузера от неправильных редиректов оставшихся от неправильных экспериментальных конфигов.

`if` в nginx не нужен почти никогда.